# Client/Server Not Receiving Data in Python

Tags: python

I am totally new to socket programming.
I have a product and trying to connect.
I can send the data and see its result on product, but I cannot receive anything.
this is my script:

```
import socket
def ScktConn():
 s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 5006))
# our local IP is 192.168.2.1, but it works even with 127.0.0.1, I don't know from where       #it is coming
 Freq=raw_input('Frequency(450-2500): ')
 CmdF='0 ace_set_frequency C1 '+str(Freq)+' \r\n'
 s.send(CmdF)
# so far I sent a tcl command to product to set the frequency and it works
 s.send('0 ace_azplayer_remove_player XXX \r\n')
# sending another tcl command and works
 s.send('0 ace_azplayer_add_player \r\n')
# here it is working too
 s.send('0 ace_azplayer_add_ace XXX C1\r\n')
 Path='C:/Users/AM_RJ/Desktop/gridview_script/PBF/4x4U_wocorr_SNR.csv'
 s.send('0 ace_azplayer_load_csvfile AzPlayer1 '+Path+' \r\n')
# here I should receive some numbers, but always returning me 0!
#even if I send ('hello!') and use recv(1024), it returns 0!
 csvid=s.recv(4096)
 print csvid
 Path2='0 ace_azplayer_edit_playback_file AzPlayer1 '+str(csvid)+' -linkConfiguration "4x4" \r\n'
 print Path2
 s.send(Path2)
```

After using `recv(4096)`, I should receive some numbers, but it always returning me `0`!
even if I send `('hello!')` and use `recv(1024)`, it returns `0`!
I'm using python 2.7.
I am not even sure whether or not the server and client sides are correct in my script!
Please help me out about it.

Comment: You'll likely have more joy if you split the send and receive into two processes.

Comment: I edited my script as follows:
But still not receiving anything, after putting Server(module name).ScktRecv(), returning me this error:
>>> import Server
>>> Server.ScktConn()
Frequency(450-2500): 600
recv: 0 ace_set_frequency C1 600 

>>> 
Server.ScktRec()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    Server.ScktRec()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ScktRec'

Comment: `ScktRec` looks like you've made a typo somehwere (should be `ScktRecv`)

Comment: should it be 5007 or 5006?I am totally new, it might seem stupid, but I really have no idea about these numbers!

Comment: These numbers are [ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)). I suggest you read some socket tutorials. [beej](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) is a good start.

Comment: >>> import Server
>>> Server.ScktRecv()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    Server.ScktRecv()
  File "C:\Users\amir_rajaee\Desktop\PKT\Server.py", line 8, in ScktRecv
    r.bind(address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Comment: I imagine you have run the script quickly in succession and the sockets have not closed cleanly. Try waiting, or using a different port (or reading about how to close sockets correctly0.

Answer (score 3):

You need more than one socket, here is a minimal example (which would need more work to be made robust). ScktConn spawns a new thread which creates a server socket that listens for the connection from `s`.

```
import socket
import threading
import time

address = ('127.0.0.1', 5007)
def ScktRecv():
    r = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    r.bind(address)
    r.listen(1)
    conn, _ = r.accept()
    csvid = conn.recv(4096)
    print "recv: %s" % csvid

def ScktConn():
    recv_thread = threading.Thread(target=ScktRecv)
    recv_thread.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(address)
    # our local IP is 192.168.2.1, but it works even with 127.0.0.1, I don't know from where       #it is coming
    Freq=raw_input('Frequency(450-2500): ')
    CmdF='0 ace_set_frequency C1 '+str(Freq)+' \r\n'
    s.send(CmdF)
```

Comment: Did this solve you issue? If so, feel free to mark this answer as accepted, else provide further information.

Comment: Should it be 5007 or 5006?!

Comment: It can be which ever port you want to use.

Comment: your guess was correct, I changes the port number , it worked, but Recv showing the TCL command  sent for frequency, not the result I need! and not even the other tcl commands coming after that frequency tcl command! Is it one use listening?

Comment: This code is an example of how to do server/client communication over sockets in the same proc. I'm not going to solve every small issue you have. At this point you need to try to understand what is going on and solve your own problems. The original problem (of not being able to receive) has been solved. Please raise any further issues in a new question.